# Remove focus from iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, focus

I have this code:

```
<iframe src="/go/afflink.php" width="100%" height="400px" seamless="seamless" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Obviously `afflink.php` is an affiliate link to an external site, so I don't have access to that.

The iframe is in the bottom of my review page. The problem is that whenever I open the page, the browser scrolls down to the bottom to show the iframe. I would like the browser to ignore the focus. How can I do it?

I searched around stackoverflow and no 'javascript focus on other element' seems to work for me.

Comment: That is unusual. Anyway, did you try this on load?

window.scrollTo(0, 0);

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

if assumed the iframe is not served from the same domain.. you can place any other focusable dom element after the iframe in the footer with autofocus set as true. And if that does not work please try the following in the parent main window:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    setTimeout(function(){$("body").focus()}, 100);
});
```

**OR going by vanilla JS**

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("some-focusable-element-from-parent-window").focus();
};
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, why `scrolling` (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_scrolling.asp) would result in the described behavior?

Comment: I did what you said but no result. Even if I remove scrolling completely it won't work. Any ideas?